# Minimize branching in C++ - Increment if value is non-zero

Tags: c++, performance, for-loop, branch-prediction

I have the following nested for-loop:

```
for(k = 0; k < n; ++k) {
    for(m = 0; m < n; ++m) {
        /* other logic altering a */
        if(a[index] != 0) count++;
    }
}
```

where `a` contains `uint32_t`. Since `n` can be quite large (but constant), and this is the only branch (besides comparing `k` and `m` with `n`), I would like to optimize this away.

The distribution of zero and non-zero in `a` can be considered uniformly random.

My first approach was

```
count += a[index] & 1;
```

but then `count` would only be incremented for all odd numbers.

In addition: I also have a case where `a` contains `bool`, but according to [C++ Conditionals](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/3483/) `true` and `false` are defined as non-zero and zero, which basically are equivalent to the above problem.

Comment: Do you know that you have a branch? (ie. Did you look at the optimized asm output?). And do you know that this branch is the main performance problem, rather than the left-out calculations?

Comment: `count += a[index] != 0;`

Comment: I do not. Is there any way to write a comment in the code, which also are found in the assembly? Since this is part of a huge code base, it might be hard to find in asm

Comment: @BetaCarotin Can I be sure that this evaluates to 1 if the condition holds? And not just some arbitrary non-zero value?

Comment: @YnkDK Yes, BetaCarotins code is guaranteed to work (standard §4.7 [conv.integral]). But as said, I guess your compiler already did this (at least if it is not VS). About the comments, depends on the compiler.

Comment: About finding the place, you could use inline asm to insert some nops and search for those.

Comment: @deviantfan It seems that you are correct. At least I'm getting the same assembly code whether or not I'm using the original method or the one proposed by BetaCarotin

Comment: Micro-optimisation on this level is pointless. Better spend time on working out where the code is slowest

Answer (score 3):

As stated in the comments for the question `if(a[index] != 0) count++;` does not produce a branch (in this case), which was somewhat verified in the assembly.

For the sake of the completeness an equivalent to the mentioned statement are `count += a[index] != 0;` (according to standard §4.7 [conv.integral])